# Cardinal Invariants and Physics

Tags: gn.general-topology, physics

There are many applications of topology to physics, but I wonder if there is a known application of cardinal invariants to physics.

Comment: there does not seem to be any...

Comment: Our chief application is surprise. Fear and surprise.

Comment: This is a really genuine question, with the hope someone knows some application, at least in theoretical physics.

Comment: Is "separable" a cardinal invariant? In quantum theory it may be useful to know that your underlying Hilbert space is separable.

Comment: If spacetime is a Lorentzian manifold, then the CH tells us there are $\aleph_1$ events in the universe. More seriously, physics, including huge parts of general relativity and quantum theory, have been shown to be formulatable in finitist foundations (this is work of Feng Ye), so it's not clear one needs even uncountable sets to describe all of nature (regardless of what nature 'really is').

Comment: Not precisely cardinal invariants, and not precisely connected with the physical universe, but Farah and Magidor did publish "Independence of the existence of Pitowsky spin models".